# INTERSECT is very slow - better solution available?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a datababase with one main table and some sub-tables. To view the data I created a C# application, that shows one large table. In this application the user can set a filter, to show only a part of all data. This filter has 20 different Parameters that can each be used or not. 
For clarity of this stored procedure I organized it like this:
For each of the 20 Parameters I create a temporary table:

```
DECLARE @tbl_parameter1 type_Int
DECLARE @tbl_Parameter2 type_Int
...
```

type_Int is a user-defined table type that only contains one column of type Int.

In the next step I fill These tables with the IDs of the main table of all rows that fit the filter-parameter. If one parameter is not set, I fill it with all IDs.

```
ID @parameter1 > 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl_parameter1 SELECT ID FROM tbl_main WHERE col1 = @parameter1
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl_parameter1 SELECT ID FROM tbl_main
  END
```

So in the end I need all IDs that occure in every of the 20 temporary tables:
This step is very slow.

```
INSERT INTO @Result 
  SELECT Value FROM @tbl_TestsequenceTags
INTERSECT
  SELECT Value FROM @tbl_Source
INTERSECT
  SELECT Value FROM @tbl_Vehicle 
... (17 more tables)
```

At the end I all another stored procedure that provides the data to the C# Application and contains all the joins and unions.

```
EXEC Get_Data @Result
```

Is there a better (faster) solution for creating the @result-Table?
Or should I do the filtering in a complete other way?

Comment: Use one query without table variables.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `type_Int` table? Please show the definition.

Comment: Wild guesss: If you put an index on the temp tables, That will make it faster.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO Thanks! That helped a lot! Without Index it takes 12667ms to execute the Intersects, With a new type, with added Index it is reduced to 78ms!

Comment: :-) Always the first port of call. 78ms may be fast enough for your needs ...

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write the query using one pass?

```
SELECT ID
FROM tbl_main
WHERE (col1 = @parameter1 OR @paramter1 IS NULL) AND
      (col2 = @parameter2 OR @paramter2 IS NULL) AND
      . . .;
```

This does require scanning the original table.  However, it should be much more efficient than writing 20 temporary tables -- many of them with ids from all rows in the original data.

Comment: For some of the parameters this would be possible. But some parameters are multi-valued (table type) and some are varchar that have to be wildcarded. So this SQL would be very very big and confusing.

Comment: @Suiram83 . . . Whatever conditions you have in your original queries you can put into a single query.

Comment: @Suiram83 I would say that the result would be less confusing and more readable because you get rid of many repetitive lines of code like `ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl_parameter1 SELECT ID FROM tbl_main
  END`.

Comment: It helped a lot to add an index to my user defined table type as suggested by Ben. Perhaps in the future I will rewrite my stored procedure like this, but for now I think this is not necessary.